# Associative Lists in Prolog

Tags: list, dictionary, prolog, predicate, associative

my task is to implement maps with lists. We defined associative lists as follows:

`[]` is the list,
`k` is a key, `v` is a value and a is an associative list, then `[[k, v] | a]` is an associative list.

so now ive got to write a predicate, in which it checks if the given argument is a associative list. 
for example:

```
?- test([[a,5]]). -> true., ?- test([[1],[2]]). -> false.
```

im really in despair, i hope someone can help me there

greetings

Comment: Note that a name starting with a lower case letter is not a variable in Prolog. `k`, `v`, and `a` are all atoms. You should probably start with a basic Prolog tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may say that [associative lists in *SWI-Prolog*](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=assoc) are implemented as an AVL-trees, not as the lists of a dotted pairs, though the latter is possible.

So, let's try your way.

> [] is the list, k is a key, v is a value and a is an associative list, then [[k, v] | a] is an associative list.

One correction:

I'd suggest `[[ k | v ] | a]` that is more compact and is "more associative" )

```
is_assoc([]).
is_assoc([[K|V] | AL]) :- %corrected 29 apr 2018 19:00 gmt+3
    !, is_assoc( AL ).


put(KV, AL, AL0) :-
   KV = [K|V],
   get(K, AL, V),
   remove(KV, AL, AL_KV),
   put(KV, AL_KV, AL0).

put(KV, AL, [KV | AL]).

get(K, AL, V):-
   member([K|V], AL).
```

Comment: @Sleeyz I hope everything is understandable?

Comment: this code is a mess. did you mean for the two puts to be named differently? even so, the 2nd will happily add anything into the list. and what is remove?