# Associative list in Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, logic, associative-array, predicate

i m doing associative list in prolog
i seen this topic but i dont understand the code.

[Associative Lists in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50069875/associative-lists-in-prolog)

For checking list is associative isn't enough do this:

```
 lists([_X, _Y]).
 lists([[H|_T]|L],[H|T]):- lists(L,T).
```

Because for first /1 i check if have element in this way [a,3]
and /2 take list of list [[a,4],[a,3]] in this way.
so first pass call list/2 on [a,3], and check true for base case, and after call [a,4] and call true for base case too.

I wrong something, but i don't see,

Anyone can clarify me?

---

OP's update of 2019-01-01 10:40:47Z:

I try to resolve in this way:

```
islist([_X,_Y]).
islist([_X|T]):- islist(T).
```

In this case accept just input in this way

```
[[k,v],[k,v],[k,v]]
```

but accept all input like this:

- [a]
- [k,v,v,v]
- [[k,v],[k,v],[k,v,v]]

So my problem remains.

Comment: That code in the answer you linked represents a key-value pair within the list as `[K|V]`, not `[K,V]`. If you want to use that code, write `[a|3]` instead of `[a,3]` for example. Your `lists` predicate has issues in that it does things differently. And your base case takes only one argument, whereas your recursive case has two arguments.

Comment: @lurker i would make a new code for understand the philosophy. I m new in prolog, i m on it. In the recursive case, i don't recall the same list of the list, but i need to maintain on element and pass at function the tail of the list of the list?

Comment: kudos for staying engaged!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the linked question:

> "`[]` is the list ; [also, if] `k` is a key, `v` is a value and `a` is an
>   associative list, then `[[k, v] | a]` is an associative list."

Just write this down in Prolog:

```
associative_list(L) :- L = [].
associative_list(L) :- K=K, V=V, associative_list(A), L = [[K, V] | A].
```

Of course Prolog as a programming language has operational concerns as well as its logical semantics, so the last line is better written instead as

```
associative_list(L) :- L = [[_K, _V] | A], associative_list(A).
```

An idiomatic way to write this is

```
associative_list([]).
associative_list([[_, _] | A]) :- associative_list(A).
```

Comment: What a pity, I was almost there!

Comment: use it as a stepping stone. :)