# Problem with getting an item out of a list

Tags: prolog

Basically I have a list with elements with the following syntax:

```
name : value
```

(all are a symbol)

So now let's say that I have such an item in a list:

```
[price : '42']
```

Ideally using

```
 nth0(0, [price : '42'], X).
```

I'd expect `X` to be `price : '42'` .

Instead what I get is `price:42` with the spaces removed.

Does anyone know why that is or maybe have a few pointers for doing this in a different manner?

(name : value must all be symbols)

Comment: You get `X = price:'42'.` as answer. Don't you?

Comment: `[price : 42]` is a list of one element. That element is the term, `:(price, 42)`.

Comment: This could probably be done using an [associative array in Prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989755/associative-list-in-prolog).

Comment: As an answer i get X = price:42 (without quotes).

Comment: try `X = price : '42', write_canonical(X), X =.. L, functor(X,F,A).`

Comment: If you do `X=price : '42', writeln(X)` it will print it without the quotes. that's just how it is written, not what it is.